# gSOAP Serialized XML to String

Tags: xml, gsoap

Anyway I can print the serialized xml message (using gsoap).

For example:

```
soap_serialize_ns1__Response(soap, &ns2__UpdatedResponse);
```

I would like to be able to see what the serialized (xml) looks like.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 7):

> Anyway I can print the serialized xml message (using gsoap).
>
> I would like to be able to see what the serialized (xml) looks like.

To "print" a serialized object to a string in XML you have two options, depending whether you are coding in C or in C++.

When coding in C do the following:

```
struct soap *soap = soap_new();
...
const char *str = NULL;
soap->os = &str; // assign a string to write output to
soap_write_ns1__Response(soap, &response);
soap->os = NULL; // no longer writing to the string
printf("The XML is:%s\n", str);
...
soap_end(soap); // warning: this deletes str with XML too!
str = NULL;     // so make it NULL as good practice
soap_free(soap);
```

When coding in C++ do the following:

```
soap *soap = soap_new();
...
std::stringstream ss;
soap->os = &ss; // assign a stringstream to write output to
soap_write_ns1__Response(soap, &response);
soap->os = NULL; // no longer writing to the stream
std::cout << "The XML is:\n" << ss.str();
...
soap_destroy(soap);
soap_end(soap);
soap_free(soap);
```

See [gSOAP XML databindgs](https://www.genivia.com/dev.html#bindings) on their web site for details.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked as below:

```
int MyService::ConfirmPayment(_ns1__PaymentConfirmationRequest *ns1__PaymentConfirmationRequest, std::string &ns1__PaymentConfirmationResult) {

   struct soap *soap = soap_new();
   std::stringstream ss;
   soap->os = &ss;
   soap_write__ns1__C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest(soap, ns1__C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest); 
   soap->os = NULL;
   std::cout << "The XML is:\n" << ss.str();

   soap_destroy(soap);
   soap_end(soap);
   soap_free(soap);

   ns1__PaymentConfirmationResult = "Transaction Queued!"
   return SOAP_OK;
}
```